# Android Billing; how to resolve "The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found"

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

With all the recent changes to the Google Billing library and the Developer Console it's hard to apply answers from 2014, so I am posting on this topic again with the hope of finding a modern answer.

I am using **Google Billing library 2.2.0**

**The Issue:**
[image]

---

**I've set up the licenses:**
[image: subscriptions]

---

**I've also set up License testing:**
[image: license testing]

---

**I've also published a release build to the internal test track (signed with release cert):**
[image: release build]

---

**Relevant Code Sample:**

```
private final String SKU_TEST_PROD_1YR = "test_prod_id_1_year";
private final String SKU_TEST_PROD_6MN = "test_prod_id_6_month";
private final String SKU_TEST_PROD_1MN = "test_prod_id_1_month";
private BillingClient billingClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<String> iapProdIdList = Arrays.asList(SKU_TEST_PROD_1YR, SKU_TEST_PROD_6MN, SKU_TEST_PROD_1MN);
    setupBillingClient(this, iapProdIdList);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    billingClient.endConnection();
}

private void setupBillingClient(Context context, List<String> iapProdList) {
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context).setListener(this).build();
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                loadAllSubscriptionProductIdDetails(iapProdList);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() { }
    });
}

private void loadAllSubscriptionProductIdDetails(List<String> iapProdList) {
    if (billingClient.isReady()) {
        SkuDetailsParams params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder().setSkusList(iapProdList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS).build();

        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, (billingResult, prodDetailList) -> {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && !prodDetailList.isEmpty()) {

                for (SkuDetails prodDetail : prodDetailList) {

                    String productSku = prodDetail.getSku();

                    switch(productSku) {
                        case SKU_TEST_PROD_1YR : {
                            final BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(prodDetail).build();
                            buttonIap1Yr.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                                // trigger purchase - Google needs the parent activity to overlay with their UI
                                billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
                            });
                            break;
                        }
                        case SKU_TEST_PROD_6MN : {
                            final BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(prodDetail).build();
                            buttonIap6mth.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                                // trigger purchase - Google needs the parent activity to overlay with their UI
                                billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
                            });
                            break;
                        }
                        case SKU_TEST_PROD_1MN : {
                            final BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(prodDetail).build();
                            buttonIap1mth.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                                // trigger purchase - Google needs the parent activity to overlay with their UI
                                billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
                            });
                            break;
                        }
                        default :
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Did not find Product in-app: "+ productSku, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }//end of FOR
            }//end of IF
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "billingClient is NOT ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> list) {

    if (billingResult != null && list != null) {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            for (Purchase purchase : list) {
                if(!purchase.isAcknowledged()) acknowledgePurchase(purchase.getPurchaseToken());
            }
        }
        else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "User Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(billingResult.getResponseCode()== BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Already Purchased", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void acknowledgePurchase(String purchaseToken) {
    AcknowledgePurchaseParams params = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder().setPurchaseToken(purchaseToken).build();
    billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(params, billingResult -> {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Purchase Acknowledged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

When I click any of my [Buy Subscription] buttons the `billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);` is correctly triggered and the SKU is correct.

As far as I am aware, all of the Dev Console is set up correctly.
I want to demo IAP to my manager, however, "The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found" is cramping my style !
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code I posted in my question is fully functional. The problem was 100% due to the developer console configuration :

**To fix it:**

1) promote the app to alpha as a **minimum** (Internal test track doesn't work!)

2) click [Manage] on the Alpha track and email the Opt-in link to your testers

3) Your testers will say "when I click this link, the Play Store says the app isn't found". Tell them to relax for 30 minutes - Google Console needs 30 minutes to process this complexity.

Have them download the early release version and suddenly IAP works!

Answer (score 0):

I think your `loadAllSubscriptionProductIdDetails()` method has a wrong design.

You only have to call `querySkuDetailsAsync()` when the user clicks, with a single item in `setSkusList()` argument, just the one to be purchased, and then :

```
  @Override
  public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
       if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList.size() > 0) {
                    BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                            .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0))
                            .build();

                    billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, flowParams);

            }

      }
```

Comment: I like that idea - I'll give it a try

Comment: The problem in your code is that the variable `prodDetail` has a unknown value at the point `onClick()` is called

Comment: yeah I see what you mean, but in my experience the lambda has always successfully made a copy of the external variable. I'll update the code (in my Question) to clarify what's going on.